# Dynamic task scheduling in php pthreads?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I'm new to php pthreads for multi-threading. I have managed to achieved my goal by building a pool, set a number of workers, use a for loop to submit task and use pool to collect result.

But I think a task is bonded to a worker when submitting to the pool. And I believe the internal logic is to make each worker get equal or as equal as possible number of tasks.

In real implementation, such logic may cause efficiency problem. For different data given to each task, it may results a large amount of time difference. Or if worker needs to communicate with server to send/get data, it also varies a lot in data transfer or even server timeout and reconnection, which results a further difference in processing different task.

For a simple example, 4 tasks are submitted to a pool which has 2 workers. Let's assume each task takes certain time to process, doesn't matter it is processed by which worker.

Task          1  2  3  4

Process Time  1s  7s  2s  4s

My understand is that in php pthreads, each worker stacks 2 tasks to be collected. And when a task is submitted to the pool, pool always stacks it to worker with fewer tasks. Assuming there is no other overhead, worker #1 processes task #1 and #3 in 3 secs while worker #2 processes task #2 and #4 in 11s. So the total pool execution would be 11s. The efficiency is very low since running all tasks sequentially takes 14s.

Another notable side effect is that worker #1 would be idling for 8 secs waiting for worker #2 to be finished. It may cause server timeout in real application. In my application, I reuse the same pool iteratively. I have to shut down the connection for idling worker per iteration and re-establish connection when it moves to the next iteration.

If a dynamic task scheduling is possible, worker #1 picks up task #1 while worker #2 picks up task #2. After 1 sec, worker #1 picks up task #3 while worker #2 still processing task #2. After another 2 secs, worker #1 picks up task #4 while worker #2 still processing task #2. After another 4 secs, they both finished and there is no other tasks remain in the pool then they get shut down. So the pool execution time = worker #1 (1s + 2s + 4s) = worker #2 (7s) = 7s. That's perfectly 2x speed up and 100% threading efficiency. Meanwhile, neither worker will idle to cause potential problems.

The above example was made up for demonstration. The real world would be much more complex. But I happen to have an application that the slowest worker run 5x longer than the fastest worker, which caused me a lot of headache.

Actually, I'm more familiar with OpenMP for C++. It provides [multiple loop scheduling methods](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling). I think the scheduling method in php threads is the static. I wish there is a way to accomplish a dynamic method.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where a single long running task on a worker would cause tasks to be stacked on that worker when there were other idle workers that could have been used.

The behaviour of [Pool::submit()](http://php.net/manual/en/pool.submit.php) according to it's documentation is:

> Submit the task to the next Worker in the Pool

For my use case I extended the Pool class:

```
namespace Task\Runner;

class Pool extends \Pool
{
    public function getIdleWorker() : ?int
    {
        if (empty($this->workers)) {
            return null;
        }

        $idleWorkerIndexes = [];

        foreach ($this->workers as $i => $worker) {
            if ($worker->getStacked() == 0)
                $idleWorkerIndexes[] = $i;
        }

        if (empty($idleWorkerIndexes))
            return null;

        return $idleWorkerIndexes[mt_rand(0, count($idleWorkerIndexes)-1)];
    }
}
```

Usage in my Task runner:

```
$workerIndex = $this->pool->getIdleWorker();
if (is_null($workerIndex))
    $this->pool->submit($taskWorkUnit);
else
    $this->pool->submitTo($workerIndex, $taskWorkUnit);
```

Calling [Pool::submit()](http://php.net/manual/en/pool.submit.php) is required to create new workers up to your pool size, then [Pool::submitTo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pool.submitTo.php) can be used to assign a task to a specific worker thread.

This method could be easily adapted to suit your own scheduling needs.